# My ProcessBuilder code does not work. Run craftbukkit from this program

Tags: java, stream, processbuilder

I tried to create a program to run craftbukkit.jar and handle input/output streams but it does not work.

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
package info.nordbyen.bukkitwrapper;

import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BukkitWrapper 
{
private final static String PATH_TO_JAVA_PROGRAM = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin";
private final static String NAME_OF_JAVA_PROGRAM = "java.exe";

private final static String PATH_TO_CRAFTBUKKIT_FILE = "C:\\l0lkj\\bukkit\\1.7.10_wrapper_tester";
private final static String NAME_OF_CRAFTBUKKIT_FILE = "craftbukkit-1.7.10-R0.1-20140808.005431-8";

private static Process process = null;
private static BufferedReader in = null;
private static OutputStream os = null;

private static Scanner scanner;

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    scanner = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.println( "Starter..." );
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( PATH_TO_JAVA_PROGRAM + "\\" + NAME_OF_JAVA_PROGRAM, "-jar", PATH_TO_CRAFTBUKKIT_FILE + "\\" + NAME_OF_CRAFTBUKKIT_FILE ); //,"--nojline"
    try 
    {
        process = processBuilder.start();
    } 
    catch ( IOException e ) 
    {
        System.out.println( "ERROR!" );
        System.out.println( e );
        System.exit( -1 );
    }
    if( process == null )
    {
        System.out.println( "ERROR!" );
        System.out.println( "process is null" );
        System.exit( -1 );
    }
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    os = process.getOutputStream();
    if( is == null )
    {
        System.out.println( "ERROR!" );
        System.out.println( "is is null" );
        System.exit( -1 );
    }
    if( os == null )
    {
        System.out.println( "ERROR!" );
        System.out.println( "os is null" );
        System.exit( -1 );
    }
    in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );

    inputHandler();
    outputHandler();
}

private static void inputHandler()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while( true )
            {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                try 
                {
                    os.write( line.getBytes() );
                }
                catch ( IOException e ) 
                {
                    System.out.println( "ERROR!" );
                    System.out.println( e );
                    System.exit( -1 );
                }
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

private static void outputHandler()
{
    while( true )
    {
        String line = null;
        try 
        {
            line = in.readLine();
        } 
        catch ( IOException e ) 
        {
            System.out.println( "ERROR!" );
            System.out.println( e );
        }
        System.out.println( currentTime() + line );
    }
}

private static String currentTime()
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "[yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss] -> " );
    Date now = new Date();
    String date = sdf.format( now );
    return date;
}
}
```

I get no errors but the input keeps returning null. Here is the console:

```
[2014-04-12 04:04:06] -> null
[2014-04-12 04:04:06] -> null
[2014-04-12 04:04:06] -> null
[2014-04-12 04:04:06] -> null
[2014-04-12 04:04:06] -> null
Etc. Etc.
```

Thank you for help :)

EDIT:
For anyone with the same problem, just add

```
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
processBuilder.redirectOutput();
processBuilder.redirectInput();
```

before creating the process as Luke Woodward said in his answer.

And for the `null` problem I just added a simple `if` statement:

```
if( line.length() >= 1 )
{
    System.out.println( Div.currentTime() + line );
}
```

I still have a problem with writing text to the process. Anyone who knows how to fix that?

Edit 2:
Everything is working now :)

Comment: What is the 'problem with writing text to the process' that you mention?

Comment: I tried to write some text in the console but the server ( the Process ) did not react to it. I changed it to a printwriter, so it works now. I forgot to update the question

Comment: OK, glad to hear you got the problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of suggestions:

(1) Call `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);`, before you create the process, to redirect the process's standard error into its standard output.  The process may be writing messages to its standard error, but if you're only reading the standard output you might not see them.

(2) When the `readLine()` of a BufferedReader returns `null`, the underlying stream has reached end-of-file.  There is no point attempting to read any more, as you will only get further `null`s.  You should `break` out of the `while` loop in `outputHandler` once the call to `readLine()` returns `null`.

I can't guarantee that these suggestions will completely fix the problem for you but they should at least help you figure out why your program is not working.

Comment: I added: `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);`, `processBuilder.redirectOutput();`, `processBuilder.redirectInput();` and now I get lines from the server. Thank you so much for this!